# How to install Silverlight in Ubuntu?

Tags: moonlight, mozilla

How do I install Silverlight plugin in Ubuntu? And how to configure browser with Silverlight plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

silverlight is not available for Ubuntu.

but you can use the free implementation of it:

pipelight or moonlight

```
sudo apt-get install moonlight-plugin-core moonlight-plugin-mozilla
```

or

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight
```

edit: just discovered that moonlight seems no more under active development [http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/moonlight/]

Comment: E: Unable to locate package moonlight-plugin-core
E: Unable to locate package moonlight-plugin-mozilla

Comment: I just discovered that moonlight is no more supported [http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/moonlight/]. Then better to use pipelight :D

Comment: sudo apt-get install pipelight and sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable its working on my pc...

Comment: Worth noting that while moonlight is no longer supported, silverlight itself is no longer supported!

Answer (score 4):

You cannot install Silverlight in Ubuntu since it is a proprietary Microsoft plugin that does not work with Linux. If you need silverlight functionality you can try your luck with [Pipelight](http://pipelight.net/cms/) which is an open source implementation of this.

You can [install pipelight](http://pipelight.net/cms/install/installation-ubuntu.html) directly from their ppa:

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
> sudo pipelight-plugin --update
> ```

Comment: can it work with mozilla firefox?

Comment: Yes, the browser should not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you can install it.

Open a terminal window. Type in the following commands then hit Enter after each:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pipelight
sudo pipelight-plugin --update
sudo pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

Answer (score 0):

From [mono-project.com](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/moonlight/):

> Moonlight isn’t actively developed anymore. If you’re feeling adventurous you can probably get it working by compiling from [source](https://github.com/mono/moon), but we recommend you move away from Moonlight as soon as possible.

Comment: you should at least provide the link to the page where this information was taken from. I've edited your answer and added the link to mono-project.com